# Rollup: Parse Error: node_modules/@stencil/core/compiler/stencil.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, rollup, stenciljs, stencil-compiler

When building my project, I get this error
[ ERROR ]  Rollup: Parse Error: node_modules/@stencil/core/compiler/stencil.js:196823:17
Unexpected token
L196822:  TaskAttributionTiming: C,
L196823:  Text: C,
L196824:  TextEvent: C,

For more info, npx stencil info display :
System: **node 18.16.1**
Stencil: **4.3.0** 
TypeScript: **5.1.6**
Rollup: **2.42.3**
Parse5: 7.1.2
Sizzle: 2.42.3
Terser: 5.19.4

***tsconfig.json***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egsci.png)

**stencil.config.ts**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9NnN.png)

Any HELP, please

I run this command **stencil build** , then build failed